# ¿Por qué me salen elementos repetidos en la lista?

Tags: java

El caso , es que estoy retornando una lista de 3 elementos diferentes , pero cada vez que hay una iteración del bucle se sobrescriben , es decir en la 2a iteración el 2o elemento se sobreescribe en la lista , y finalmente el 3er elementos sobreescribe a los dos anteriores.

```
@GetMapping("/find")
    public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getFindMonedas() {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Moneda> monedas = monedaService.getMonedas();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> listaDef = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Moneda m : monedas) {
            map.put("id", m.getId());
            map.put("fechaInserccion", m.getFechaInsercion().toString().replace("T", " "));
            map.put("fechaModificacion", m.getFechaModificacion().toString().replace("T", " "));
            map.put("nombre", m.getNombre());
            map.put("abreviatura", m.getAbreviatura());
            map.put("pais", m.getPais().getId());
            listaDef.add(map);
            System.out.println(listaDef);
        }
        return listaDef;
    }
```

La salida que me está dando al hacer el System.out.println en cada **iteración**:

```
[{fechaInserccion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, fechaModificacion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, abreviatura=eur, id=1, nombre=euro, pais=2}]
[{fechaInserccion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, fechaModificacion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, abreviatura=lib, id=2, nombre=libra, pais=5}, {fechaInserccion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, fechaModificacion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, abreviatura=lib, id=2, nombre=libra, pais=5}]
[{fechaInserccion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, fechaModificacion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, abreviatura=yen, id=3, nombre=yen, pais=3}, {fechaInserccion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, fechaModificacion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, abreviatura=yen, id=3, nombre=yen, pais=3}, {fechaInserccion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, fechaModificacion=2021-04-28 09:57:02, abreviatura=yen, id=3, nombre=yen, pais=3}]
```

Lo que quiero es que en la listaDef se me pongan los tres elementos distintos. No sé que está pasando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tú error se encuentra en la forma en que manejas la variable  `HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();`, cuando iteras debes de crear un nuevo `map` para agregar los valores, lo que haces es almacenar en `listaDef.add(map);` la misma referencia `map` en cada iteración y al modificar la referencia siempre terminas con el ultimo elemento repetido por cada moneda que iteras.

La solución es instanciar la variable `map` por cada moneda y almacenar esa variable en la lista.

```
   @GetMapping("/find")
    public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getFindMonedas() {          
        List<Moneda> monedas = monedaService.getMonedas();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> listaDef = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Moneda m : monedas) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("id", m.getId());
            map.put("fechaInserccion", m.getFechaInsercion().toString().replace("T", " "));
            map.put("fechaModificacion", m.getFechaModificacion().toString().replace("T", " "));
            map.put("nombre", m.getNombre());
            map.put("abreviatura", m.getAbreviatura());
            map.put("pais", m.getPais().getId());
            listaDef.add(map);
            System.out.println(listaDef);
        }
        return listaDef;
    }
```

Comment: Cierto! No me había dado cuenta..que fallo..! Gracias

Comment: Que bueno poder ayudarte, este tipo de error es más común de lo que piensas, de ahora en adelante seguramente ya lo resolverás fácilmente.